# ggplot2: Keep x-axis labels in non-alphabetical order

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using ggplot2 to plot the annual occurrence of events in states. I want the state labels to be in the same order as shown in the data table "AZ CT NH NM DE..." but ggplot automatically reorganizes the state labels in alphabetical order "AZ CT DE NH...". I created groups so I could display ranges in "num" values (ex. NM and TN). Please ignore the group numbering--I took out some data points to make the table smaller.

[image]

```
ggplot(guidelines, aes(x = state, y = num, group = grp)) +
geom_point() + geom_line(linetype = "dotted") +
labs(x = "State", y = "Number") + 
labs(title = "A") +
scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 11, 1), 
                  limits=c(0,11))
```

[image]

I have tried the suggestions of previous posts to use factor and levels like so:

```
guidelines$state <- factor(guidelines$state, levels = unique(guidelines$state)
```

But it does not work because I am using groups and repeating state names. Any ideas on how to get around this?

Comment: I think you're looking for `scale_x_discrete`

Comment: Please don't add data as an image. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 3):

We can use `ordered`

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

guidelines %>% 
   mutate(state =ordered(state, levels = unique(state))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = state, y = num, group = grp)) +
       geom_point() + 
       geom_line(linetype = "dotted") +
       labs(x = "State", y = "Number") + 
       labs(title = "A") +
       scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 11, 1), 
                   limits=c(0,11))
```

-output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You were close in that you must use `unique()`. Adding `ordered=T` inside the `factor()` will keep the desired order. Here the code (Please next time share your data using `dput()` as sometimes it can be complex to use data from screenshots in they are really big):

```
library(ggplot2)
#Data
guidelines <- data.frame(state=c('AZ','CT','NH','NM','NM','DE','NJ','TN','TN'),
                 num=c(10,10,10,5,10,5,5,2,5),
                 grp=c(3,4,17,19,19,5,18,25,25),stringsAsFactors = F)
#Format factor
guidelines$state <- factor(guidelines$state,levels = unique(guidelines$state),ordered = T)
#Plot
ggplot(guidelines, aes(x = state, y = num, group = grp)) +
  geom_point() + geom_line(linetype = "dotted") +
  labs(x = "State", y = "Number") + 
  labs(title = "A") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 11, 1), 
                     limits=c(0,11))
```

Output:

[image]

Or as mentioned in comments by **@TTS** you can use this the `scale_x_discrete()` with `limits` option:

```
#Data
guidelines <- data.frame(state=c('AZ','CT','NH','NM','NM','DE','NJ','TN','TN'),
                         num=c(10,10,10,5,10,5,5,2,5),
                         grp=c(3,4,17,19,19,5,18,25,25),stringsAsFactors = F)
#Plot 2
ggplot(guidelines, aes(x = state, y = num, group = grp)) +
  geom_point() + geom_line(linetype = "dotted") +
  labs(x = "State", y = "Number") + 
  labs(title = "A") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 11, 1), 
                     limits=c(0,11))+
  scale_x_discrete(limits=unique(guidelines$state))
```

Output:

[image]